# localScale is not working at the runtime after applying the Animator component

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, scale, animator

I apply an animator component to my Game Object. After that when I play the game, I try to change the localScale of the game object but it doesn't work.

[image: The Animator Component]

Here is my code to change the game object's localScale according to its direction on the x coordinate.

```
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Vector3 direction;
private Animator anim;
private bool isLookingRight;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    isLookingRight = false;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    TurnDirection(horizontal);
}

// turns the player towards to movement direction
private void TurnDirection(float horizontal)
{
    if (horizontal > 0 && !isLookingRight || horizontal < 0 && isLookingRight)
    {
        isLookingRight = !isLookingRight;
        direction = transform.localScale;
        direction.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = direction;
    }
}
```

It worked well before applying the animation to the Game Object. I can't change the scale of the Game Object even manually on the inspector while playing the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by keyframes controlling localScale in the animation file. If you don't need it, you can solve the problem by deleting these keyframes from the animation window.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPtu0.png)

Comment: Thank you so much. One of my animations has a scale, when I delete that animation, the problem has fixed. 

The weird thing is I was not running that animation that has the scale.